# Insert list of multiple values in SQL table using pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a list of length greater than 5 million rows. I need to insert this list into a table in my database using pyodbc. I tried 2 methods but both take a lot of time.

My list looks like this:

```
    a=[3000200,3000201,3000202, ...]
```

Code which I have tried so far (Assume table TEMP created already and mylist.csv has all values of list a):

1. Create a csv file and insert from that (takes 1.5 hrs to create csv file):

   ```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TEMP SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'mylist.csv' USING (DELIMITER ',' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC')")
   ```
2. Insert from list by using loops(ETA is over 120 hrs!):

   ```
   b='INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (?)'
   for i in tqdm(a):
     cursor.execute(b,i)
   ```

Is there an easier way to perform this insert without waiting so long ?

EDIT

For Code 1, I was using a 'for' loop to insert the values of a string into a csv file and this was taking far too long than necessary.
As mentioned by Gord in comments below, I converted the list into a dataframe and loaded it (Using code 1) with 'to_csv' method and it takes less than a minute now!

Comment: What database are you using, and are you accessing it locally or over the network?

Comment: @GordThompson I am using an IBM Netezza db and accessing it locally.

Comment: Also, 1.5 hours to write 5 million rows to a CSV file is highly suspicious. My old notebook can write a DataFrame with 5 million rows to a CSV file on my desktop in less than 30 seconds using pandas' `to_csv` method.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson! I had a list and was inserting into a file through a 'for' loop. This is why it took so long. I just converted the list into a df and used the to_csv method. Now it takes less than a minute.